# expect telnet - command not executing

Tags: shell, tcl, expect, telnet

I am struggling with executing command via telnet/expect.

```
set send_slow {500 .5}
send -s -- "show slot *\r"
expect {
    ".*>" {
        send -s -- "y\r"
        exp_continue
    }
    ".*#\s"
}
send -s "who\r"
expect "# "
send -s "alm\r"
expect "# "
send -s -- "logout\r"
```

`show slot` command prints card in slots. Due to paging user is asked to continue. After execution that a prompt `NODE2-1#` is shown and I want to execute command `who`.

What I get is:

```
2/36 PF                   Empty                Up      Down    UEQ
2/37 FAN                  FAN                  Up      Up
2/38 Empty                Empty                Down    Down    UAS UEQ
2/39 Empty                Empty                Down    Down    UAS UEQ
25/1 SFD40                SFD40                Up      Up

Node2-1#<br> Node2-1# who

Session          Username                          Date         Terminal
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
116 (cli tel) *  admin                             May 29 06:57 XX.X.XX.XX

Node2-1# almlogout

Alarm Status:  Critical-3    Major-0    Minor-0
```

As you can see, first prompt is left empty and in second one there is a command. It takes few seconds to execute it.

Moreover, below one can see, that in prompt there is pasted command `almlogout`. These two are separate commands -> `alm` and `logout`. However, they are pasted together.

Question is - how to execute command in prompt without that delay, and second - how to separate two commands

Answer (score 2):

By default, `expect` statement's pattern is in glob style so `".*>"` should be `-re ".*>"` and `".*#\s"` should be `-re ".*#\\s"` or `-re {.*#\s}` (`"\s"` is actually `"s"`).

And since `.*` can match nothing, so `-re {.*>}` is the same as `-re {>}` and `-re {.*#\s}` the same as `-re {#\s}`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have done some corrections. However, now script outputs:

Comment: plz ask new questions for new problems.